# Matching only Arabic and English Alphanumeric with one space allowed only

Tags: php, regex, validation, arabic

I have got a forum site and I am currently working on the final piece, the registration form and I want to validate the username. It should only contain Arabic and English alphanumerics and a maximum of one space between words.

I've got the english alphanumeric part working but not the Arabic nor the double spaces.

I am using the `preg_match()` function to match the username input with the RegEX.

What I currently have:

```
!preg_match('/\p{Arabic}/', $username) && !preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/')
//this is currently inside and if statement, so if they both don't match then it is false.
```

Comment: @chris85 I have got the second part fixed. Silly me :D, but I don't understand what you mean "inside your character class"..

Comment: @chris85 this is working smoothly for the English but not in Arabic, it still does not accept it. here's what I have now.
`if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\p{InArabic}]+$/', $username)){`

Comment: There is no `In`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145830/discussion-between-beginnerp-and-chris85).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the unicode properties inside your regular regex because this can all be done with 1 regex. You also need to quantify that character class otherwise you only allow 1 character. This regex should do it.

```
^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\p{N}]+\h?[\p{N}\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z]*$
```

Use the `u` modifier in PHP so unicode works as expected.

PHP Usage:

```
preg_match('/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\p{N}]+\h?[\p{N}\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z]*$/u', $string);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fsRchS/2/